# Best way to add fileSystem to existing http api web server

Tags: go

I already have a web server and it work fine, now I want to add the fileSystem module to it.

OverView of the project under below.

```
// Custom router

type Handler func(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error

type Middleware func(Handler) Handler

type App struct {
    mux      *chi.Mux
    och      *ochttp.Handler
    mw       []Middleware
}

func NewApp(mw ...Middleware) *App {
    app := App{
        mux:      chi.NewRouter(),
        mw:       mw,
    }

    app.och = &ochttp.Handler{
        Handler:     app.mux,
        Propagation: &tracecontext.HTTPFormat{},
    }

    return &app
}

func (a *App) Handle(verb, path string, handler Handler, mw ...Middleware) {

    handler = wrapMiddleware(a.mw, handler)

    h := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ...
    }

    a.mux.MethodFunc(verb, path, h)
}

func (a *App) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    a.och.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}




// route

func API(...) http.Handler {

    app := web.NewApp(mid.Logger(log)...)

    s := Something{
        ...
    }

    app.Handle("GET", "/v1/somthing", s.DoSomething)

    return app
}



// Handler

type Something struct {
    ...
}

func (s *Something) DoSomething(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    ...
}




// main

api := http.Server{
    ...
    Handler:      API(...),
}

go func() {
    api.ListenAndServe()
}()
```

The app struct is a custom router, it contains 3rd router, trace library and some middleware. The type Handler is the specific Handler format using for Middleware and any api handler register to this router. Because this project hard code only one Handler, what's the best to add another Handler like fileSystem to it?

Answer (score 1):

http.Handler and Handler conversion through closure.

```golang
// http.Handler to Handler
func NewHandler(h http.Handler) Handler {
    return func(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}

// Handler to http.Handler
func NewHTTPHandler(h Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        h(context.Background(), w, r)
    })
}

// or Handler implement http.Handler
func (fn Handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fn(context.Background(), w, r)
}

app.Handle("ANY","/fs/*", NewHandler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))
```

`type Handler func (Context)` is the best Handler definition. Request the context.Context object through `http.Request.Context()` or the top-level context.Context is obtained through the `http.Server.BaseContext` property.

Middleware's best implementation idea has two methods used by the echo or gin framework, but the echo method should not copy the memory allocation waste.

It is recommended to implement the router by yourself. In the mainstream framework and routing inventory, **does not have routing priority**, such as a large number of libraries such as echo gin httprouter gorilla/mux.

The following is the framework and the simplest implementation that I designed for 22 months.

my web framework: https://github.com/eudore/eudore

simple framework: https://github.com/eudore/eudore/wiki/3.2-frame-mirco-web

Comment: fei chang gan xie